# Why is dto being converted to Map?

Tags: java

I've been trying to understand why is the searchDto being converted into Map. The following function is called to get customer that matches by the given search word which comes from Angular form.

```
 public Page<Customer> getCustomerFromCustomerLoan(Object searchDto, Pageable pageable) {
        List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> s = objectMapper.convertValue(searchDto, Map.class);
        s.put("distinctByCustomer", "true");
        s.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
        logger.info("search param for customer in customerLoan {}", s);
        final CustomerLoanSpecBuilder customerLoanSpecBuilder = new CustomerLoanSpecBuilder(s);
        final Specification<CustomerLoan> specification = customerLoanSpecBuilder.build();
        Page<CustomerLoan> customerLoanPage = customerLoanRepository
            .findAll(specification, pageable);
        customerLoanPage.getContent().forEach(customerLoan -> {
            if (!customerList.contains(customerLoan)) {
                customerList.add(customerLoan.getCustomerInfo());
            }
        });
        List<Customer> finalList = customerList.stream().filter(distinctByKey(Customer::getId))
            .collect(
                Collectors.toList());

        Page<Customer> pages = new PageImpl<Customer>(finalList, pageable,
            customerLoanPage.getTotalElements());
        return pages;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when asking why someone did something in a specific way all we can do is make educated guesses - unless there's some documentation on the reasoning behind this. In this case my *guess* would be that since `searchDto` is of the type `Object` it could actually be one of several types, e.g. a plain json string, an already parsed pojo etc. - converting that to a map makes the information in that dto available in a quite generic way.

Think about apis that actually use distinct pojos that share some properties, in the case of a `CustomerLoan` let's say those might be  `customerNumber`, `loanAmount`, `customerName`  etc. 
One could now use a DTO that just has `customerNumber` and `loanAmount` while the other has `customerNumber` and `customerName`. If you convert those DTOs to a map you get a generic structure that you can pass to `CustomerLoanSpecBuilder` and that class in turn can check whether there's a value for those properties.

Granted, you could probably use interfaces along with `instanceof` but that might be tedious as well.

I'll try to clarify with an example:

Using a map could look like this:

```
Map<String, String> props = ...;
if( props.get("customerNumber") != null ) {
   //add predicate for customer number
}
if( props.get("customerName") != null ) {
   //add predicate for customer name
}
if( props.get("loanAmount") != null ) {
   //add predicate for loan amount
}
```

If you want to provide a clean api using interfaces would require 3 separate interfaces, e.g. `ICustomerNumber`, `ICustomerName`, `ILoanAmount` (I don't actually like those names but they should make their meaning somewhat clear):

```
class DTO1 implements ICustomerNumber, ILoanAmount { ... }
class DTO1 implements ICustomerNumber, ICustomerName { ... }
```

Now using those could look like this:

```
Object inputDto = ...;
if( inputDto instanceof ICustomerNumber ) {
   //cast to ICustomerNumber, get the value and add predicate for customer number
}
if( inputDto instanceof ICustomerName ) {
   //cast to ICustomerName , get the value and add predicate for customer name
}
if( inputDto instanceof ILoanAmount ) {
   //cast to ILoanAmount , get the value and add predicate for loan amount
}
```

Another alternative would be to use reflection to check whether there's a method called `getCustomerNumber()` and if so calling it but you don't want to go down that route.